# How to use CompletableFuture inside a sqs queue listener in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, completable-future

I am working on a spring boot app where I am receiving a callback from a 3rd party api and that 3rd party also expects a response.

There are multiple db operations that I need to perform and to avoid data inconsistency during load I am using a SQS queue to push data and do all the operation.

The Thing is I also want to send the response back to the 3rd party immediately and the DB operations will be running in the background.

How is this possible with the **SQS** queue and **CompletableFuture**?

Here's the snippet:

```
// this method is a SQS Listener. 


 public PaymentCallback acceptPaymentForPendingOrders(String callbackRequest) {
        PaymentCallbackRequest paymentCallbackRequest = decryptCallBackResponse(callbackRequest);
           
        // here's all the DB operations I am doing async.
        CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            @Transactional
            public void run() {
                try {
                    orderSettlingRequest.setPaymentId(savedPayment.getId());
                    ResponseEntity response = orderServiceClient.settleBtoBOrders(orderSettlingRequest);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //credit the full amount to wallet of the user
                    log.error("Error occurred while settling b2b orders using credit",e);
                }
            }
        });
       
        //sending response immediately not waiting for asnyc operations.
        return paymentCallbackRepo.save(paymentCallback);

    }
```

Can I do this when using queue? Is this feasible?

Comment: CompletableFuture is used to chain async operations. I think you would be better off using a thread pool (executor service), and submitting the DB operations to it.